# how to get background image present in other folder using css?

Tags: html, css, background-image, external

Guys this is my folder structure

Project

- index.php
- css

  style.css
- js

  javascript.js
- image

  background.jpeg

style.css

```
body{
background-image: url("image\background.jpeg");
}
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "header">
    hiuiiiii
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So guys tell me where am i wrong such that i can correct it so that my background image is displayed.

Comment: Please indicate what steps you have taken to troubleshoot the problem yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the issue.

**Incorrect** - url("image\background.jpeg");

**Correct** - url("../image/background.jpg");

`../` - This means one directory up to give the image location, as in your case, it is inside image directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try with ../image/ - @ManiKandan

Answer (score 2):

It should look like this:

```
body {
     background-image: url("../image/background.jpeg"); }
```

That is a really common mistake, even with me. You need the double dots to go back one folder, since your stylesheet is inside the css folder and your background is inside the images folder.
Also, once you get that fixed, you could perfectly align it in the back using

`background-size: cover`;

.. and with the prefixes, it would look like this.

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: y so big description friend . anyway thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 2):

URLs in CSS are relative to the directory containing the CSS file. Were your file in the root directory, your URL would be correct. However, as its in a "sibling" directory to the image you wish to use, you'll need to add `/` or `../` to it. Also, URLs on the web always use forward slashes `/` rather than backslashes `\`.

```
body{
    background-image:url("/image/background.jpeg");
}
body{
    background-image:url("../image/background.jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
background:url("../images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
```

or

```
background-image:url("../images/background.jpg");
```

use `../` before folder name

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got same problem when i try your problem it locally. But now, i make it works like.

**CSS:**

```
body{
background: url("../image/background.jpg");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <title>Todo Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "header">
    hiuiiiii
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this could help :url("../image/background.jpg");

Comment: This is just a repeat of the existing answers.